# Material-UI DataGrid not sorting numeric column correctly

Tags: reactjs, sorting, datagrid, material-ui

I am currently working on `DataGrid` Component from Material-UI. Data can be displayed, but the inbuilt sorting is not working as expected. When I try to sort ASC/DESC it is sorting based on the first digit of the number. Please look into the picture below:

[image: Descending Order]

I have tried the same with fake API in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-leakey-eu3cq?file=/src/App.js). It is working fine but in my application the sorting is acting different.

Then I have tried to add `sortModel` (followed Material-UI Sorting docs) still it is acting the same. I haven't been able to find a solution in the docs.

```
const sortModel = [{ field: "canaryDeviceId", sort: "asc" }];

<div style={{ height: "90%", width: "100%" }}>
  <DataGrid sortModel={sortModel} rows={rows} columns={columns} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `DataGrid` columns by default use string comparator, if you want to sort numeric column, try setting the type to `'number'`:

```js
{
  field: "deviceID",
  headerName: "Canary DeviceID",
  type: "number",
},
```

> Then I have tried to add sortModel (followed Material-UI Sorting docs) still it is acting the same.

`sortModel` only describes the sorting state of `DataGrid` so I doubt it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for that, you saved me 5 hours of stack overflow search lol

Answer (score 0):

```
sortComparator: (v1, v2) => parseInt(v1) - parseInt(v2),
```

work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Type Number value coming from API server side and will display a different value with modification      
        
        { field: "controlTriggerLowerVal", headerName: "Lower Trigger", width: 150 ,type: "number",headerAlign: "left",
                              renderCell: (cellValues) => {
                                return  <> {cellValues.row.calculateLowerTrigger} </>;
                              },flex:1,align: 'left'
                              
    
    Another way to write custom sort , also handles null and space:
    
    nullSpaceHandlingSortComparator = (
        v1,
        v2,
        cellParams1,
        cellParams2
      ) => {
        const sortModel = cellParams1.api.getSortModel();
        const sortColumn = sortModel.find(
              (sm) => sm.field == cellParams1.field
        );
        if (sortColumn && sortColumn.sort == "desc") {
            if ((v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 == "" && v2 == "")) {
            return -1;
            }
            if ((v1 == null) || (v1 == "")) {
            return -1;
            }
            if ((v2 == null) || (v2 == "")) {
            return 1;
            }
          return v1 - v2; 
        }else{
    
          if ((v1 == null && v2 == null) || (v1 == "" && v2 == "")) {
              return 0;
          }
          if ((v1 == null) || (v1 == "")) {
              return 1;
          }
          if ((v2 == null) || (v2 == "")) {
              return -1;
          }
          return v1 - v2;  
        }
      };

 { field: "controlTriggerLowerVal", headerName: "Lower Trigger", width: 150 ,type: "number",headerAlign: "left",
                  renderCell: (cellValues) => {
                    return  <> {cellValues.row.calculateLowerTrigger} </>;
                  },flex:1,align: 'left',
                  sortComparator: this.nullSpaceHandlingSortComparator,
                  }
```